# Google Pie Chart Visualization - color as variable outputs invalid color on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, google-visualization

I use pie charts from Google Visualization Charts.

In my example I load the color codes from CSS and put them as hex values in variables.
Those variable are used to setup the colors for the pie chart.

The issue:

On Firefox desktop this works without any problem. When I test the page on my mobile using Chrome it says

`Invalid color: ...`

When I use colors with direct input as string hex code it works on both mobile and desktop. I cannot see why it does not work. Any ideas?

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['mass', 'percentage'],
          ['var',     40],
          ['vartwo',      30],
          ['varthree',  15],
          ['varfour',  15],
        ]);

// get the colors
var element = document.getElementById('section-header');
style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
colorone = String(style.getPropertyValue('--color-graphics-one'));
colortwo = style.getPropertyValue('--color-graphics-two');
colorthree = style.getPropertyValue('--color-graphics-three');
colorfour = style.getPropertyValue('--color-graphics-four');
colorfive = style.getPropertyValue('--color-graphics-five');

// working in desktop version
colors = [colorone, colortwo, colorthree, colorfour, colorfive];

// working in both desktop and mobile
colors = ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6'];


        var options = {
          title: 'Diesen Projektfokus planen wir',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        colors: colors,
legend: { position: 'bottom', alignment: 'center' },
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piecharttwo'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
</script>
<div id="piecharttwo" style="display: block; width: max-width; height: 300px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you verified the correct color is making it to the variable when on mobile using chrome?

Comment: When I run it on my mobile it mentiones "Invalid color: #A84098". Which is atually the right color hex code. I also checked it via document.write, the hex code is there.